# Finding the value with minimum absolute difference of all absolute differences in python

Tags: python

I have 2 tables:

Table A

[image]

and Table B

[image]

For each value in Table A, I want to get the value from Table B which has the minimum absolute difference with the value in Table A. Also, since it might be the case that the same value in Table B might have minimum absolute difference with more than 1 value in Table A, each value in Table B can only be used once to match with a value in Table A.

The final table should look like this:

[image]

After asking ChatGPT,I tried below

> 

```
results = {}

for x in A['MTM_VALUE']:
    for y in B['MTM_VALUE']:
        min_diff = min(abs(A['MTM_VALUE'] - B['MTM_VALUE']))
    closest_value = min(B['MTM_VALUE'], key = lambda a: abs(a - A['MTM_VALUE']))
    B['MTM_VALUE'].remove(closest_value)
    results[x] = (closest_value, min_diff)
```

However, I get errors. And it'd be best to have the matching values from Table B in a dataframe.

Comment: You never use `y` in the loop. That should raise a red flag.

Comment: You don't use `x` or `y` when calculating `min_diff`. So it's the same every time through the loop.

Comment: You need to generate a cross product of the two dataframes. The calculate the minimum of the absolute difference gruoped by column A.

Comment: If you sorted table B and take the first and last items, what would that allow you to do?

Answer (score 0):

We can apply the solution [`here`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-closest-number-to-k-in-given-list/) for a dataframe:

```
lst=table_b['MTM_VALUE'].tolist() #convert table_b values to a list

def closest(lst, K):
     lst = np.asarray(lst)
     idx = (np.abs(lst - K)).argmin()
     return lst[idx]
table_a['closest']=table_a['MTM_VALUE'].apply(lambda x: closest(lst, x))
```

Or one line:

```
table_a['closest'] = table_a['MTM_VALUE'].apply(lambda x: lst[(np.abs(np.asarray(lst) - x)).argmin()])
```

**Output**:

```
   ID  MTM_VALUE  closest
0   1      12.54     15.36
1   2      16.84     17.36
2   3       5.00      2.00
3   4     152.96    160.00
4   5      48.36     42.91
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I see it returns the minimum value from table b for all rows in table a.

Comment: I did not understand. Could you elaborate a little more on the problem?